# How to map fetched JSON to the existing object in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular-httpclient

I have a problem with mapping fetched JSON from the API to an existing object.
TypeScript code:

[image]

Hero Interface:

```
export interface Hero {
   id: number;
   name: string;
}
```

Console log:

[image]

`this.hero` is always empty (undefined). How to solve this
PS. I'm new in  Angular and typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the return type is an array. So you probably need to access the first element (or similar).

```
this.hero = fetchedHero[0];
```

Comment: No, I've followed Angular tutorial and they have property initialization like hero: Hero; and I get an error: "Property 'hero' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor." So I've marked the parameter as optional (hero?: Hero;). I think that the problem lies there...

Comment: if you look in your console.log output the response is [{...}] which is an array.   followed by element 0 being displayed

Comment: Yeah, you were right. My API returns List and .ts expects one object... What an amateur. Thank you for your time!

Comment: you're welcome - that's what SO is for :-)  .  if you wouldn't mind accepting this as answer it'd be great - many txs

Answer (score 0):

API was returning a LIST and ANGULAR/.ts was expecting one object. Because of that, mapping didn't succeed. After changing the return value of GET HTTP REQUEST from LIST to one object, mapping started to work!